# Writing log file in temp folder by IExpress

Tags: wix, cmd, windows-installer, iexpress

I'm using IExpress to generate .exe installer.

I want to make it generate log file into temp folder like this.

```
msiexec /i MyPackage.msi" /l*v "%temp%\MyPackge.log"
```

but after a bit of research I found that `IExpress` use `command.com` not `cmd.exe` so that it doesn't understand `%temp%`

So, I try changing it to

```
cmd.exe /c msiexec /i MyPackage.msi" /l*v "%temp%\MyPackge.log"
```

it seems work but there is a command prompt appears while installing which is not nice at all.

Anyway to fix this ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I end up with this.

```
msiexec /i MyPackage.msi" /l*v "..\MyPackge.log"
```

because the .msi has been extracted to %temp%\MyProduct, that's why I can use "..\MyPackage.log"

Answer (score 1):

you can choose to install /q quiet with no UI and /norestart options
msiexec command line options http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa367988%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

Answer (score 1):

You can hide the `cmd.exe` window by changing the *Show window* option to *Hidden* in the IExpress Wizard. In the `.sed` file, this would be:

```
ShowInstallProgramWindow=1
```